# Best way to share httpClient instance between activities?

Tags: android

In an Android app what's the best way to **share an http client instance**?

I know I should probably just share the session data and create an http client instance for each activity but excluding that approach how can I achieve my objective without globally sharing an instance created in one of the activities (as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-beginners/esg8toyHVek))?

How can I share objects using ***getContext()*** in each activity?

Thanks

Comment: Create a singleton class which is holding reference of httpclient.

Comment: And then how do I share it between activities? Thanks

Comment: Please look the solution provided if you have some different scenario then define here. Thanks

Comment: So should I just make my activities implement a shared interface that extends AppCompatActivity and contains the httpClient singleton?

Comment: Oh I see so in every activity I'll just import ApiManager and get the singleton..

Comment: did it solve your problem or not?

Comment: Yeh, think so. I'll try later. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a singleton class with initializer method and after that all Activities can get http client by

```
ApiManager.getInstance().getClient();



   public static class ApiManager {
        private static ApiManager sInstance;
        private HttppClient mClient;
        private ApiManager(Context pContext){
            mClient = new HttpClient(pContext);
        }

        public static void initializer(Context pContext){
            if(sInstance == null){
                synchronized (ApiManager.class){
                    sInstance = new ApiManager(pContext);
                }
            }
        }

        public static ApiManager getInstance(){
            if(sInstance == null){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Get Instance can't be called before initializer");
            }
            return sInstance;
        }

        public HttppClient getClient() {
            return mClient;
        }
    }
```